# Out-of-Fold sample predictions using xgboost with xgb.cv

Tags: boosting

Is it possible to get the out-of-fold predictions when applying xgboost with xgb.cv? With randomForest, predict(RFfit) gives you the OOB predictions (resulting from the CV process); with gbm, fitgbm$cv.fitted gives you the OOF predictions (somewhat similar to CV predictions). However, I have not found something similar with xgb.cv or xgboost.

Comment: A now-deleted answer had a useful comment, I think: out-of-**bag** predictions don't make sense in gradient boosting.  But as for out-of-**fold**, see the current answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

In the R package, `xgb.cv` has a [parameter](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xgboost/versions/0.4-4/topics/xgb.cv#l_arguments) `prediction` (which defaults to `FALSE`); setting it to `TRUE` should expose the out-of-fold predictions as the `pred` attribute.  See also the [Values section](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xgboost/versions/0.4-4/topics/xgb.cv#l_value) of the documentation, which confirms the output should be the out-of-fold predictions.

There doesn't seem to be a similar functionality for the python package.  You could use the `sklearn` API and `sklearn`'s `cross_val_predict`.

Comment: As far as I know, predict=T is not possible if you apply xgb.cv. You get: "Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class xgb.cv.synchronous". If you use the xgboost function, instead of xgb.cv, predict=T does work, but I assume it gives you the predictions on the training samples. I tried and the "prediction" was too good (compared to RF) to be a true CV prediction.

Comment: The parameter is `prediction`, not `predict`.  It works for me, with `out <- xgb.cv(...)` then `out$pred`.

Comment: Right, with xgb.cv the predictions by CV are obtained with fitxgb$pred, and using xgboost (instead of xgb.cv) the predictions on new data are obtained with predict(fitxgb, newdata).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that if it is possible to find out the optimal number of iterations by CV using xgb.cv, it should be possible to get the predictions that were obtained in that CV. That is, at least, what I assumed gbm gives you with fitgbm$cv.fitted. What I'm not sure is that that's the OOF predictions.